# what is the difference between " Beware" and "Be Aware" ?

Tags: meaning

Can you please explain what is the difference between " Beware" and "Be Aware" ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

"Beware" indicates danger, and "be aware" merely calls attention to something.

For example:
"Beware of the dog" - it might bite you.
"Be aware of the dog" - you might trip over it in the dark.